# Windows 10 DISM error: 0x800f081f

Tags: windows-10, dism, sfc

I have been trying to run `sfc /scannow` in `cmd` but have been unsuccessful. Therefore, after some research on  the Internet, I turned to the following command:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:X:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

where `X` indicates the drive letter where the Windows .iso is mounted.
(I mounted the .iso file using Daemon Tools)

However, I keep getting the following message:

> Error: 0x800f081f
>
> The source file could not be found.

I'm not tech savvy, but after skimming over the `dism.log`, I found this line that may or may not have something to do with the error.

```
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt

amd64_microsoft-windows-microsoftedge_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16397_none_19381f0c8accd5dd\MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png
```

I really do not wish to reset or refresh Windows because there are just so many programs I will have to reinstall. I would appreciate any help.

On a side note, Windows Update Diagnostic reports that the Windows Update service registration is missing or corrupt, which it failed to fix as well, if this means anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've fixed this "Error: 0x800f081f" affecting a PC with Window 10 Pro-32 by running

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:E:\sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

Only the Windows 10 ISO downloaded from [Techbench](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) and mounted in E: with Daemon Tools worked. Other ISO downloaded with Windows 10 media-creation-tool did not work at all, returning the same error 0x800f081f, even when converted from the embedded ESD format to WIM, using NTlite, and mounted using either Daemon Tools or DISM GUI.

Also all other attempts to fix the error from Windows Update Live had not worked before, always returning same error 0x800f081f, i.e. by using:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Update 08/08/2016: As Techbench link above no longer works please give a try to the following link (note that I have not tested yet if it is the same kind of ISO which was formerly available from Techbench. Please report your results):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/

Comment: The author ran the exact same command, the question itself, is about the error that is generated when they run that command.  This also appears to be a near duplicate answer to Noseratio's answer.

Comment: The error in my opinion lies on the fact that not all the Win 10 ISO are the same. The same command run with the ISO downloaded from techbench works, whilst if run with the ISO downloaded by Media Creation tool, it doesnt. Additionallly there's a significant difference from the answer from Noseratio: I had no need to incorporate Windows 10 cumulative Updates, I just had the need to find the right ISO and for this I indeed give my thanks to Noseratio!

Comment: An answer should answer the author's problem not your own.

Comment: An answer should be help full to someone else who has the same problem, as the authors has already fixed the issue by re-installing Windows

Comment: a_big_friend, which iso version did you take on technet ? Cause it doesn't work for me neither and I can't access windows update catalog website to update the install.wim. Please help me, I'm turning crazy right now with all those W10 bugs.

Comment: From Techbench I simply selected the Win 10 Edition that was best fitting my Win 10 installation: Windows 10, Italian, 32-Bit Download. No need to specify if PRO or HOME, as I understand that the ISO downloaded from Techbench is including both. As I said, with this ISO, that was significantly bigger than the one that I had downloaded before with the Media Creation Tool, the DISM command worked without any complaints properly restoring the health. Clearly you have to select and try from Techbench the ISO that is better fitting your system.

Comment: I can confirm this also works for 64bit windows. Dont even need Daemon Tools - just mount it with standard Windows utility and point source: to it

Comment: @a_big_friend.  I fought the standard ISO for a whole day.  The TechBench ISO was the answer.

Comment: link is not working... please update the link

Comment: Please try the following link (note that I have not tested yet if it is the same kind of ISO which was formerly available from Techbench. Please report your results): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/

Answer (score 6):

I've fixed the same problem by running `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:C:\Users\User\Downloads\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess` against an updated `Install.wim` with the latest Windows 10 Cumulative Update slipstreamed ([KB3081452](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081452) and [KB3095020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3095020) at the time of this post). There's no need to repackage an .ISO.

Basically, I followed the ["Add updates to customized Windows"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt186619(v=vs.85).aspx) guide from Microsoft itself:

```
md C:\mount\Windows

Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\Images\install.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\mount\Windows

Dism /Add-Package /Image:C:\mount\Windows /PackagePath:C:\MSU\Windows10-KBxxxxxxx-x64.msu /LogPath:AddPackage.log

Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\mount\Windows /Commit
```

Those who don't have a copy of the original un-encrypted `Install.wim` file may find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3ee1gx/windows_10_10240_esd_download_here/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3gn3r0/an_attempt_was_made_to_load_a_program_with_an/) helpful.

**Updated**, I did another in-place upgrade on two other household PCs, Windows 8.1 -> Windows 10 x64, using the [Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install) and the "Keep nothing" option. After installing all updates (including the latest cumulative update KB3093266), both PC failed the `"sfc /scannow"` test and the `"dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth"` recovery, same error `0x800f081f`.

So, I repeated the procedure described above, this time using a Windows 10 ISO from [TechBench](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) and slipstreaming the [KB3093266 MSU](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/crup/2015/09/windows10.0-kb3093266-x64_6751b43720389771ff946993ed0def5a7ec4acc3.msu) into its `install.wim`. Problem fixed.

**Updated**, the issue re-surfaced after upgrading to Windows 10 Version 10.0.10586.0 (November 2015 Update + latest cumulative update). This time, I simply downloaded the latest ISO from [TechBench](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), mounted it and executed `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:E:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`, then `sfc /scannow`. Apparently, there's no need to slipstream the latest cumulative update.

**Updated**, the issue re-surfaced once again on a different PC. This time I coudn't find the ISO (has TechBench gone?), so I had to use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10), create a USB drive installation, then convert `install.esd` into `install.wim`:

`dism /export-image /SourceImageFile:d:\sources\install.esd /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:c:\temp\install.wim /Compress:fast`

Then repair the image using Windows Update as backup (i.e., without `/LimitAccess`):

`dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:C:\temp\install.wim:1`.

Then repair the system files:

`sfc /scannow`.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this as well?

Comment: @Skipher - *You are the only one who can confirm if this works or not.*

Comment: My answer to this question states that I no longer have this issue as I have chosen to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Skipher  The TechBench ISO is good.  It's confirmed.  See answers above by a_big_friend.

Comment: I can confirm this is still valid. Had a computer die on me after using Disk Cleanup to try to reclaim some space (pro tip: don't do that). Only thing for me is dism refused to work offline and wouldn't find the replacement payloads. So what I ended up doing was running `dism /ScanHealth`, looking at the logs, then with the wim image still mounted, manually copying the offending files over (i.e. from `c:\mount\Windows\Windows\winsxs\<component>\*` to `c:\Windows\winsxs\<component>`).

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the parameter `/source:WIM:X:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`. Windows 10 has version `10.0.10240.16384` and the corrupted file has version `10.0.10240.16397`. So the file is not part of the Install.wim. Without the `/source` parameter DISM will download the corrupted files from WindowsUpdate and replace them.

Comment: I've used the /source parameter because the command without a specific source also gave me the same error, and I was hoping to repair it with an .iso file. What can I do to overcome this error? Also, is the error message "The Windows Update service registration is missing or corrupt" related in any way to the problem you addressed? Thanks.

Comment: inject the older UpdateRollup https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3074683 into the install.wim (http://woshub.com/integrate-windows-updates-into-windows-8-image/) and now use the /source command to point to the new WIM. Does this work?

Comment: I ended up doing an in-place reinstall of Windows 10 because of the frustration, but thank you for providing this new idea! I have never heard of it before, and I will definitely try it the next time my Windows acts up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, tried with the other solutions in this post but none worked.

This one worked:

1. download Windows 10 ISO from [Techbench](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
2. mount the iso
3. assuming D is the drive letter of the mounted iso, run the following in an elevated command prompt:

   `Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`

Comment: link isnt working, please update the link

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply did an in-replace reinstall of Windows. I did not want to lose all my programs, so I chose not to refresh or reset Windows, and there was no remaining method of repair that would work.

Answer (score -1):

OK, thanks for all the instructions and hints on this topic.

I did get my DISM problem solved with following steps:

- having Windows 10 ISO 1511 10586.0 (maybe .493?) already on an USB stick
- first copied the E:\sources\install.esd into C:\
- then converting the C:\install.esd getting it into ...\install.wim and copied it into C:\
- then running the -> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:C:\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
- finally noting that a successful Cleanup done

Great! Next I can once again go on chasing my original problem -> [Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade error 0xc1900101 - 0x30018 referring to SYSPREP](https://superuser.com/questions/1113521/windows-10-anniversary-upgrade-error-0xc1900101-0x30018-referring-to-sysprep) , let's see what now happens with it ...