# Windows 10 SFC and DISM errors

Tags: firefox, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, dism, sfc

First of all, I know this is a duplicate but there was no real answer to the other question [Windows 10 DISM error: 0x800f081f](https://superuser.com/questions/951538/windows-10-dism-error-0x800f081f) and I'm still not allowed to comment. :/

My original problem is an annoying glitch: every time I close a file browser window (tried firefox and internet explorer) whether for saving or opening a file, the application will freeze for a few seconds. I found references to this particular issue around the internet, never a clear solution (someone solved by *failing* a system restore... go figure). It's around since windows 7 at least. Since the problem affects more than one application I assumed it system wide and acted accordingly.

I run

```
sfc /scannow
```

The tool detects problems but is unable to correct them so I tried with dism after some searching.
I tried both

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

and

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:c:\10pro64\sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

with the very same results that the tool can't find a source for the files, error: 0x800f081f.

In all honesty I don't know what to do, could be a corner case. This is an upgrade to Windows 10 that occurred just a few days ago. Can't pinpoint exactly when it started, right away or after an update (which occurred almost immediately).

The funny bit is that if I manage to fix the detected problems it may not even solve the original glitch, it could be unrelated but I *do* want to solve this as a first step.

These are the logs for sfc and the second dism command line https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwn9Gr8UrRT7RVdxNUd5eHBKTDg/view?usp=sharing

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\10pro64\sources\install.wim /english

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Details for image : c:\10pro64\sources\install.wim

Index : 1
Name : Windows 10 Pro
Description : Windows 10 Pro
Size : 13.752.408.824 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: look for the indexes. Index 1 maybe Home which doesn't have the file. Try **wim:2**

Comment: @magicandre1981 unfortunately it didn't help. Same error. `dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\10pro64\sources\install.wim /english

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Details for image : c:\10pro64\sources\install.wim

Index : 1
Name : Windows 10 Pro
Description : Windows 10 Pro
Size : 13.752.408.824 bytes

The operation completed successfully.`

Comment: I've extracted the package "Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base" into a CAB: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hwt2d3rqykeycp/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0 Try to add it with **DISM /Add-Package /packagePath:<full path to CAB>**. If this fails, extract the CAB and use the extracted data folder and source parameter.

Comment: @magicandre1981 sir, you are my personal hero. Add-Package didn't make a difference but extracting the cab and using the folder as a source DID! Lo and behold, the original problem seems solved too! sfc found and fixed additional problems with success and dism reports no further problems. Please post an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the log and saw that file `MMAgent.psd1` from the package `Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base` is corrupted.

I've extracted the package into a CAB. [Download it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hwt2d3rqykeycp/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=1), extract the CAB and point to it as source in the DISM command

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:C:\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384
```